# Error: EACCESS permission denied VSCODE in debian 10

Tags: xampp, debian, htdocs

Please help me Guys, I use VisualCode on Debian 10, when I add or delete files on htdocs directory[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSQdi.png). VsCode doesn't permit me to do this action.

Comment: Maybe you need to stop the web server?

Comment: my web server doesn't work

Comment: @Martin The issue is solved, I used this command 'sudo chown -R myuser /path/to/folder' and it worked well.

Comment: Nice, congrats then, and well done!